# Contract for plumber vs roofer

Tags: united-states, contract-law

When one creates a contract in a specific business domain, are there parts of a contract that do not need to be enumerated as the type of work already includes implied constraints. i.e. A contract with a plumber is part of one domain and a contract for roofing is part of another domain and a roofer needs to supply a tarp in case of inclement weather. A plumber, as it is usually indoors, would likely not be concerned with inclement weather. Would it be implied that a roofer as minimum standard must provide provision for inclement weather?

Note this could be any business domain. These were picked as just examples.

If there are parts of a contract that are implied, not enumerated,  for specific domains, what is it called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the United States, in general, one should err on the side of assuming that nothing is implied in a contract for services like plumbing or roofing.

Unlike Europe, where a great deal is implied in law or with a minimal contract language trigger, in the United States, very little is implied. As a result, U.S. contracts are frequently ten times as long as European contracts and are much more expensive to draft.

Sometimes a court will imply that workman-like performance of the task requires certain steps or precautions to be taken, but as a practical matter, any time you can think of anything particular that should be done, the better practice is to expressly provide for it in the contract or scope of work document.

For example, a duty to clean up the work-site after the work is done is not consistently held to be part of the job unless the contract expressly says so.

Comment: Dislike this answer, but from what I have read is true. I just do not see how a homeowner, who does not have domain expert knowledge, would know what should be expected of a plumber or roofer. I suppose then during researching bidding, really research the proposal and ask for the contract that would be signed while gathering bids.

Comment: @paulj Unless you are very sophisticated indeed, as a practical matter you are better protected by looking for a contractor with a good reputation and positive reviews (and a lack of negative Better Business Bureau interactions) than you are by having a tight contract.

Answer (score 8):

### It's unwise to rely on an implied term

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The circumstances where a term will be implied into a contract are limited, and if disputed, proving the existence or otherwise of an implied term is a dispute that wouldn't be necessary if the parties had made the term explicit.

**Business efficiency**

A term will be implied if the contract can't function without it. The criteria were set out by the House of Lords in *[BP Refinery (Westernport) Pty Ltd v President, Councillors and Ratepayers of The Shire of Hastings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BP_Refinery_(Westernport)_Pty_Ltd_v_Shire_of_Hastings)* (1970) CLR 266 at p 283 (my emphasis):

> 1. it must be reasonable and equitable:
> 2. it must be necessary to give business efficiency to the contract, **so that no term will be implied if the contract is effective without it**;
> 3. it must be so obvious that **'it goes without saying'**;
> 4. it must be capable of clear expression;
> 5. it must not contradict any express terms of the contract.

While it might 'go without saying' that a tarpaulin is necessary while the roof is off, it doesn't 'go without saying' that the roofer is the only one who can provide it. There might be a case between a homeowner and a roofer but between a builder and a roofer, it does not 'go without saying' who is responsible for weather protection.

Incidentally, the decision I had to write to qualify as an Expert Determiner turned heavily on implied terms and BP.

**Custom or usage**

The test was set out in *Con-Stan Industries of Australia Pty Ltd v Norwich Winterthur Insurance (Australia) Ltd* 1986 CLR 226 at pp 236-237:

> 1. The existence of a custom or usage will justify the implication of a term into a contract is a question of fact ...
> 2. There must be evidence that the custom relied on is so well known and acquiesced in that everyone making a contract in that situation can reasonably be presumed to have imported that term into the contract ...
> 3. A term will not be implied into a contract on the basis of custom and usage where it is contrary to the express terms of the agreement ...
> 4. A person may be bound by a custom notwithstanding the fact that he has no knowledge of it ... a person would be presumed to know of the usage if it was of such notoriety that all persons dealing in the sphere could easily ascertain the nature and content of the custom. It would then be reasonable to impute that knowledge to a person notwithstanding their ignorance of it.

**Previous course of dealing**

Where the parties have a pattern of commerce, it may be implied that they intend that pattern to continue. That is, a contract concluded with missing terms will imply that the previous way those were dealt with will continue to be the way they are dealt with.

**Statute**

Various statutes imply terms in contracts, including fitness, merchantability, and description of goods. Sometimes, the parties can limit or exclude these, while others are non-excludable.

In recent times, legislative practice has tended to create statutory rights outside the contract rather than implying terms. For example, the consumer guarantees on the supply of goods and services are 'freestanding' outside the contract and exist even if the contract is void.

**Uncertain, meaningless, and ambiguous terms**

Courts will 'fill in the blanks' to deal with these, providing that they do not make the contract itself uncertain, meaningless, or ambiguous. That is, they will imply terms to make a contract work, but not to make a contract.

Answer (score 5):

Normally, this would be covered by the [standard of care clause](https://www.adamsdrafting.com/exploring-the-standard-of-care-in-services-agreements/) in the contract. You would normally require that the service provider perform their tasks "professionally", "in a workmanlike manner", or some other standard.  If there is a dispute, the judge would then have to make a determination about whether a roofer's provisions for inclement weather were professional.  There are a variety of different standards that are common in different industries that impose higher or lower burdens.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative jurisdiction answer: [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

If the person purchasing the services from the contractor is a consumer, then the [Consumer Rights Act 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/2) is applicable. [Section 49(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/49) provides:

> Every contract to supply a service is to be treated as including a
> term that the trader must perform the service with reasonable care and
> skill.

[Section 57(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/57) provides:

> A term of a contract to supply services is not binding on the consumer
> to the extent that it would exclude the trader’s liability arising
> under section 49 (service to be performed with reasonable care and
> skill).

As noted in [Justin Cave's answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/101175/3066), it would then be up to a court to decide whether exposing an open roof to rain would be a breach of the reasonable care and skill requirement.